# wcf client through proxy

Tags: wcf, proxy

hay all.
maybe you have an answer
i have a client that need to go to my service but he is using proxy server, i have problem with the ssl connection. i have read a lot of answers, but what do i have to use in the end?

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" >
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

or something else ?
thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes in client configuration add:

```
<defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
  <proxy bypassonlocal="True" proxyaddress="http://..." />
</defaultProxy>
```

And make sure that binding has useDefaultWebProxy="true" (should be default value).